# AngularJS variavel de escopo não atualizando

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Estou com um problema bizarro com uma variável que criei no próprio HTML com o AngularJS. Eu inclusive tentei instanciar ela no Controller para ver se era esse o problema mas não.

Tenho um botão que no `ng-click` eu digo que essa variável (que ainda não foi instanciada) se torna o oposto dela. Para o botão funciona. Ela vem `null` primeiramente, mas ao clicar no botão algumas vezes ela ganha valor e se torna `True` ou `False` (de acordo com o clique). Eu exibo essa variável dentro do botão e ela funciona. Agora se eu tento usar ela em outro lugar, ela não funciona.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="nova_variavel_criada = !nova_variavel_criada;">{$nova_variavel_criada$} . {$nova_variavel_criada ? 'PRIMEIRO CASO':'SEGUNDO CASO'$}</button>
AQUI ELA NÃO PRINTA NENHUM RESULTADO: {$nova_variavel_criada$}
```

Sobre o `{$ $}` é porque uso Django e tive que mudar as chaves.

Dentro do botão, ao clicar, acontece a mudança da frase normalmente. Inclusive o print atras aparece "TRUE" e "FALSE" de acordo com o Clique. O problema está fora do botão, nada aparece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinceramente não entendi o que rolou. Minha solução foi chamar uma função e lá dentro fazer a mudança. Dessa forma a variável de escopo muda em todo template.

HTML

```
<button type="button" ng-click="change_variavel()">{$nova_variavel_criada$}</button>
{$nova_variavel_criada$}
```

Angular

```
$scope.change_variavel = function() {
    $scope.nova_variavel_criada = !$scope.nova_variavel_criada;
}
```